# Surface area of quarter of a Sphere

Tags: geometry, area, solid-geometry

A quarter sphere with a radius of $10 \text{ units}$.
 
Please help, also remember the sides. 
I used the normal formula of the total surface area of a sphere and divided it by $4$, then added half the area of a circle but it wasn't equal to the correct answer.

Comment: try adding $\frac 34$ area of a circle

Comment: You forgot the bottom side, so you need three quarters of a circle, not two.

Comment: So 1/4(4(PI)(10)^2) + 3/4( (PI)(10)^2 ) ?

Comment: When I tried it like edited below, the answer matched

Answer (score 1):

Let's first try to imagine the quarter of the solid sphere:

[image: semihemisphere]

It has a curved surface and $2$ mutually perpendicular plane surfaces

$$\text{T.S.A} = \underbrace{\frac{1}{4} 4\pi r^2}_{\text{curved surface area}} + \overbrace{\frac{1}{2}\pi r^2 + \frac{1}{2}\pi r^2}^{\text{Plane surface surface}} = 2\pi r^2$$

Comment: What did you use to make the diagram?

Comment: @LarsH: Google Images... lol